# Bootstrap 3 - Input zoom on iOS looks odd with input-group-addon

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-safari

I am using Bootstrap 3 on my current project and on my login page, I used the input-group-addon for the first time. My code currently looks like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></div>
  <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" required placeholder="E-Mail">
</div>
```

When I open the page on my iPhone with Safari and click the input field, it zooms in to the input field (centering it), as it always does. However, in this case it looks very odd due to the addon being left to it. Is it possible to center the entire "input-group", instead of just the input field, while still enabling the user to enter the input?

Thanks in advance! If any code is missing or you are looking for more information, I would be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out now, that the zoom-effect occurs in Safari mobile, when the font-size of the text field is < 16px. Setting the font-size to 16px resolved the issue for me, as my input field with the addon was centered before and is no longer additionally zoomed in.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, the `select` element needs to have the `focus` pseudo-class attached.

```
.form-control:focus{
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: I am not looking for a way to center the text within the input field.
The browser "zooms" towards the input field, so it is in the center of the screen (without moving its actual position within the page, only the viewport). I want it to zoom to the entire form-control div instead.

Comment: EDIT: However, changing the general font-size (not in :focus) to 16px for form-control fields removed the zoom-functionality (safari decides like this), which lead to the desired outcome, as my fields were naturally centered before and are no longer additionally zoomed! Thanks!